# Does the In Rhythm talent stack with itself?

Tags: the-division-2

Can you get a 10% or 15% chance by having this talent on multiple weapons?

**In Rhythm**

> While equipped, enemy kills have a 5% chance to refresh active skill cooldowns. Can occur once every 60 seconds.

Comment: If they shared a global timer it might increase proc chance, but still only once every 60s.